# Scala, Lift | SHtml.select - how to put list from database

Tags: forms, scala, lift

I'm trying to put into form ( `select` ) some values from database:

```
val kateg = Kategoria.findAll.map(a => (a.id.toString , a.nazwa))
```

And next in form:

```
 bind("entry", xhtml,
        "kateg" -> SHtml.select(kateg, Empty, select ), 
       "temat" -> SHtml.text(temat, temat = _),
        "opis" -> SHtml.textarea(opis, opis = _, "cols" -> "80", "rows" -> "8"),
        "submit" -> SHtml.submit("Add", processEntryAdd))
```

And then i have error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
type mismatch;  found   : List[(java.lang.String, a.nazwa.type) for 
Some { val a: code.model.Kategoria }]  
required: Seq[(String, String)] Forma.scala 
/lift-todo-mongo/src/main/scala/code/snippet    
line 51 Scala Problem
```

any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHtml.select(..)` allows you to choose a `String` value.
It takes a Seq of tuples (Value: `String`, Key: `String`)

In that case you probably need to write:

```
val kateg = Kategoria.findAll.map(a => (a.id.toString , a.nazwa.is))
```

if **nazwa** is `MappedString` field of Kategoria entity.
i.e. **kateg** should have a type of `Seq[(String, String)]`

But I would suggest you to use `SHtml.selectObj` to select Kategoria entity instead of String name value:

```
val kateg: Seq[(Kategoria, String)] = Kategoria.findAll.map(a => (a, a.nazwa.is))
SHtml.selectObj[Kategoria](kateg, Empty, (k: Kategoria) => { .. /* assign */ .. })
```